# Why PyCharm cannot find reference when typing Union of two classes

Tags: python, pycharm, syntax-highlighting, typing

PyCharm highlights: "cannot find reference 'object_var' in 'Foo | Bar'

There is no highlight with 'class_var'.
The code is running ok, without errors.

```
from typing import Union, Type


class Foo:
    class_var = "fo"

    def __init__(self):
        self.object_var = "o"


class Bar:
    class_var = "ba"

    def __init__(self):
        self.object_var = "r"


def foo_bar(file_object: Union[Type[Foo], Type[Bar]]):

    class_var = file_object.class_var
    object_var = file_object.object_var

    return class_var, object_var
```

[code with highlighted part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9wYu.png)

Comment: That's to be expected though, no? At least that's what I understood from reading https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type.

Answer (score 0):

`Type[Foo]` describes a class definition that inherits `Foo` or `Foo` itself, this declaration is not about instances, see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-type-of-class-objects.

Since `object_var` is an instance variable in the both cases, PyCharm correctly raises the warning.

What's the usage of `foo_bar`? I suppose type hint should be `file_object: Union[Foo, Bar]`.